# how to open an app with flutter alarm manager

Tags: android, dart, flutter, alarmmanager

is flutter android alarm manager plugin can open an app  ?

i'm try to create a reminder app but android alarm manager plugin just can print some things not any more !

**Main Code :**

```
void main() async {
  final int helloAlarmID = 0;
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(minutes: 1), helloAlarmID,appRunner);
}
appRunner() {
  return runApp(new MaterialApp(home: new AlarmShow()));
}
```

**Alarm Show Class :**

```
class AlarmShow extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('alarm'),
            new Icon(Icons.alarm)
          ])));
  }
}
```

I expect this show AlarmShow class but it not

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Is alarmShow a widget that you wrote? if yes, provide the body. the better way is following the alarm [manager docs](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/android_alarm_manager)

Comment: @Yamin yes it's return a Scaffold and some things in it , are you mean to put my scaffold straight inside the function ?

Comment: Agha provide more details and code. I should be able to run and debug your code.

Comment: @Yamin Ok i added the alarm show code

Comment: any news for this issue ?

Comment: You can go native. Here is a GitHub issue thread with more information https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32617

Comment: I think [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67563237/14434806) I wrote earlier will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a bug with wakeup](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/android_alarm_manager_plus/issues/7) that I've just made a PR for fixing it